AWS: How to terminate EC2 instances when deleting Auto Scaling Group
I use the following CloudFormation template to create AWS Auto Scaling Group:
ECSAutoScalingGroup:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  DependsOn:
    - ECSCluster
    - EC2Role
  Properties:
    VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref SubnetIds
    LaunchTemplate:
      LaunchTemplateId: !Ref ContainerInstances
      Version: !GetAtt ContainerInstances.LatestVersionNumber
    MinSize: 0
    MaxSize: !Ref MaxSize
    DesiredCapacity: !Ref DesiredCapacity
    NewInstancesProtectedFromScaleIn: true
  UpdatePolicy:
    AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
      WillReplace: 'true'

When I delete a CloudFormation stack created with this template, deleting the Auto Scaling Group takes so long and then fails, because there are running EC2 instances.
How can I make sure that EC2 instances are automatically stopped and terminated when I delete the CloudFormation stack, which in turn, deletes Auto Scaling Group?

To do that you can configure the AutoScalingRollingUpdate behavior so that instances are properly terminated during updates and deletions.
I tried this configuration, and it worked without any issue, deleting the ASG and instances:
ECSAutoScalingGroup:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  DependsOn:
    - ECSCluster
    - EC2Role
  Properties:
    VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref SubnetIds
    LaunchTemplate:
      LaunchTemplateId: !Ref ContainerInstances
      Version: !GetAtt ContainerInstances.LatestVersionNumber
    MinSize: 0
    MaxSize: !Ref MaxSize
    DesiredCapacity: !Ref DesiredCapacity
    NewInstancesProtectedFromScaleIn: true
  UpdatePolicy:
    AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
      WillReplace: true
    AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
      MinInstancesInService: 0
      MaxBatchSize: 1
      PauseTime: PT5M


Maybe I am wrong, but according to the AWS documentation, what you've specified for AutoScalingRollingUpdate attribute is the default value. It means that even if I don't specify the attribute explicitly, it should work with default values. Am I missing anything here?

And even when specifying it, it still doesn't work? Weird if it's not working for you with the same conf. What's exactly the error?
